# Python file permission

Tags: python, arcgis-server, linux

When I create a .sddraft it by default gets Owner's read and write permissions. I think I need execute permission for creating .sd file. 
I am using Python and my file resides in LINUX server.

Comment: you must have write permission to the directory to create a new file.

Comment: Did you install server as root?

Comment: yes and my parent directory has read write and execute permissions. but when I am creating a new file in the folder it gets only read and write permission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a file in linux ownership is going to be assigned to the creator.  You need to change ownership or add your user to a common group in order to publish the `sddraft`.

Comment: I am working as an owner group and I already changed the file permission of folder manually but when I creates a new .sddraft it only gets read and write permission from parent folder.

Comment: Thats correct you draft is going to be read and converted with `arcpy.StageService_server`  are you unable to run it?

Comment: yes I was thinking it might need execute permission. can we change permissions in python?

Comment: no and you don;t need to... Publishing services is a three step process `arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft()` then `arcpy.StageService_server()` and finally `arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server()`  you only need to be able to read the draft file it is not an executable file type

Comment: yes! i am trying the same steps but I was getting an error  "Consolidating the data failed". I was thinking File permissions are the last option toward the service definition file.

Comment: Thats a different problem http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00vp0000002r001270

Comment: oh yes I worked on this link already. after your comments it is decided that sddraft is only for reading purposes and execute permission is not required. Great!